# GM-AM-QM inequalities for complex numbers?!

Tags: complex-analysis

To my surprise I could not find the HM-GM-AM-QM inequalities for complex numbers! ( inequality between Arithmetic-Geometric and Quadratic mean for complex numbers)

Can anyone help me finding them? I am specially interested in inequalities between quadratic mean and arithmetic means of $n$ complex numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no inequalities for complex numbers.

Comment: For the AM-GM i could find only one paper :https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/anly/22/3/article-p277.xml

Comment: but i am interested in QM-AM inequality.....

Comment: what kind of inequality are you interested in qualitatively? in other words, given $n$ complex numbers with some conditions on their arguments, what is that you would like to prove with them as the question is a bit vague?

Comment: we have n complex z1,z2,...zn ( lets say inside unit circle) is there an inequality between (z1+z2+...+zn)^2  and z1^2+...+zn^2  ?

Comment: How are you defining $z<w$ when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, Mehrdad? The complex numbers do not form an ordered field.

Comment: yes you are totally right ,   what if we take absolute value

Comment: If you take the absolute value, you might as well just work with nonnegative real numbers and we already know that situation well.

Comment: Is the geometric mean of complex numbers even defined ?

Comment: if we take absolute value only in the end?....

Comment: @Mehrdad: please think about the exact problem you want to solve and tell us.

Comment: did you see the paper i mentioned? plz

Answer (score 2):

A comment that got too long to try and clarify the problem -

the paper linked optimizes an inequality of the type $(\Pi_{k=1}^n |z_k|)^{1/n} \le C(n,\phi)|\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{z_k}{n}}|$ in the case $|\arg z_k| \le \phi < \pi/2$ (which is a necessary condition for such inequalities since otherwise, the sum can just cancel)

However it is not hard to prove that when the arguments are like that, $|\sum {\frac{z_k}{n}}| \ge A(\phi)\sum {\frac{|z_k|}{n}}$, so the usual GM-AM inequality can be applied and the question reduces to the optimization of the final constant; in your case, it's not clear what you want qualitatively as again with appropriate argument bounds one can get reverse triangle inequalities with some constant so one can apply the usual AG-QM inequality etc

For example if $|\arg z_k| \le \psi < \pi/4$ there is a constant $A(\psi)$ (for example $\cos (2\psi)$ works) st $|\sum \frac{z_k^2}{n}| \ge A(\psi)(\sum \frac{|z_k^2|}{n}) \ge A(\psi)(\sum \frac{|z_k|}{n})^2 \ge A(\psi)|\sum \frac{z_k}{n}|^2$ and again the argument condtion is necessary since otherwise one can easily make $\sum \frac{z_k^2}{n}=0$ and then one can look into how to optimize $A(\psi)$ for the final inequality etc, but not sure exactly what the problem here requires

Edit later - to prove the above inequality one notices that for $|\arg z_k| \le \psi < \pi/4$ we get $|\arg z_k^2| \le 2\psi < \pi/2$, so $\Re z_k^2=|z_k^2|\cos \arg z_k^2 \ge |z_k|^2 \cos 2\psi$ so $|\sum \frac{z_k^2}{n}|\ge \sum \frac{\Re z_k^2}{n} \ge \cos 2\psi(\sum \frac{|z_k^2|}{n})$ so we can take $A(\psi)=\cos 2\psi$ as noted and then

$|\sum \frac{z_k}{n}|^2 \le \frac{1}{\cos 2\psi}|\sum \frac{z_k^2}{n}|$

Note that as per the paper quoted in the Op, there is a chance that the constant can be optimized further

Comment: Thank you Conrad !...i am exactly looking forward to something as you write here...( where it is proven ? paper ?...where can i look ) thank you for your clear help.

Comment: added a quick proof for the inequality with $1/cos (2\psi)$ as inequality constant but again there is a good chance that factor can be optimized more

Comment: thank you very very much :)......( it would be fascinating to discover the best possible constant here )