# Ordering Arithmetic, Geometric and Harmonic mean absolute values.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Simple query. Among the three means (AM,GM, Harmonic mean) of a number pair is the inequality correct?

$$ AM \ge GM \ge HM $$

EDIT1:

Is the inequality valid for complex numbers? For a pair of complex numbers (not ordered on a single line as for real numbers) can the three absolute mean values be compared?

[image]

Comment: What is the arithmetic mean of $-1,-2,-3$?  What is the harmonic mean of $-1,-2,-3$?

Comment: Well known about AM,GM ok. Checked them numerically to be ok, I have in  mind a geometric picture of a circle cut by a line from an outside point ordering them that way.

Comment: For positive real numbers, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities. For complex numbers the question makes no sense, because complex numbers are not ordered.

Comment: For the absolute values of complex numbers, see e.g.  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3700824/42969

Comment: Thanks sir for the link, was wondering if it would make sense at all.

Comment: No problem – I found all these links with Google in less than 30 seconds :)

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is correct if all the quantities upon which it is being applied are positive.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is correct. However AM,GM and HM $∈ $ $W$(Whole Number)

Edit: To those who might get confuse whole numbers are the set of all positive numbers as well as the number 0. [See more about it here](https://byjus.com/maths/whole-numbers/)

Comment: If “whole number” means “integer” then your statement is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR I guess you are confused. Whole numbers are the set of all positive numbers and 0. See more about it here https://byjus.com/maths/whole-numbers/

Comment: There seem to be different meanings of that term. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number, “whole numbers” can stand for the positive, non-negative, or all integers.

Comment: @MartinR I am not exactly doubting Wikipedia but I guess there is some problem in wikipedia actually i am referring whole numbers as the first point mentioned in your link